# expo: Is it possible to build ios standalone app and run on device directly

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I saw one of the post showing how to build and run standalone app on ios simulator

1. Run exp build:ios -t simulator to create an iOS standalone simulator
   build
2. Wait for build to finish then download and unpack YourAppName.tar.gz
3. Start iOS simulator and run xcrun simctl install booted
   YourAppName.app

Is there a way to run directly on iOS device

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: im facing the same problem currently and have no solution. I want to run it on a real iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has ‘simctl’ binary to interact with iOS simulators from command line.

`xcrun simctl install booted yourappname.app`

More information can be found [here](https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc).

Comment: Can I run an expo build on my physical device? (not within the Expo app and not on a simulator)

Comment: xcrun simctl install booted yourappname.app